# Redirect with Mason 1.0

Tags: perl, redirect, mason

I am using Mason 1.0 and want to redirect the page to another URL.

Is there any way to redirect?

Alternatively...

I have written following code in `dbhandler` which is giving error, stating that `$r` is undefined. Can you please help.

```
$r->method('GET');
$r->headers_in->unset('Content-length');
$r->content_type('text/html');
$r->header_out('Location' => $newPageURL);
$m->abort(301);
```

I cannot use `$m->redirect` as it is not avalible to me.

I am referring to this link http://www.masonhq.com/htmlmason/wiki/FAQ:HTTPAndHTML on the section "How do I do an external redirect?"

Comment: You haven't shown enough of your code for me to be able to answer. Write a short, complete example which exhibits your problem. See [this section](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise) of esr's "smart questions" article.

Comment: In particular, why do you expect `$r` to be defined? Have you defined it yourself, or have you done something to get Mason to define it?

Comment: I havenot defined it myself and its not compulsory for me to use it. I am just looking for alternative to $m->redirect() method which is avaible in mason1.1x version

Comment: I am new to mason and as i said i am just referring one of the sites http://www.masonhq.com/?FAQ:HTTPAndHTML#h-how_do_i_do_an_external_redirect_ . Should i define $r as i understood that use Apache2:subrequest will make it avaible to me in my componenet.

Comment: Why would you use almost 10 years old software?

Answer (score 1):

```
$r->status(302);
$r->headers_out()->add("Location", "http://google.com");
return 302;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `$m->clear_buffer` is missing before your first call.

It's required so it wipes out any response generated before you reach your redirection.